# Any gotchas in moving files from db into the file system?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a horrid system to work with and one of the flaws in it are files frequent to change, in a database. We are planning to move the files to the filesystem and just store a file path in the db. Is there anything we should be aware of while doing this ? Any file locking issues when multiple requests require copying and then sending the same file over the web asynchronously ?

Comment: These are Crystal Reports rpt files, we need to copy the whole byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If a website process acquires a handle on a file (in the file system), it will lock the file.  This means that you cannot delete the file while the website process is running.

In order to work around this, ASP.NET shadow copies the files it knows about to a temporary location.  This allows it to acquire the lock (on the shadow copied file) while leaving the origin file unlocked.

So, you might want to [consider this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx).  Concurrency management is what a database is good at.  The file system would need extra care depending on how the process is using the files.

Comment: I guess as long as you just read them it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with crystal report rpt files in ASP.Net application. They are stored in the file system and I have never seen any issues during multiple access